# celery chord, is not executing the callback function

Tags: python, flask, celery

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import  group, chord, chain

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379',
)
celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    print("starting task adding " + str(a) + " & " + str(b))
    return a + b

@celery.task()
def finish_callback(results):
    print('Group task finished')
    return 0


@app.route('/group_task')
def task_group():
    short_tasks = [add_together.delay(10, 1),
            add_together.delay(10, 3),
            add_together.delay(10, 4),
            add_together.delay(10, 5),
            add_together.delay(10, 6)
    ]

    callback = finish_callback.s()
    chord(short_tasks, callback)

    return 'Executing Parallel Task'
```

I have a Flask application where I have have some background operation which has subtasks. Iam trying to solve this problem with celery. In above code snippet, chord is not calling the callback method. All the tasks are successfully executed, but callback method is not executed. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with above code?

Comment: Are you using redis?

Comment: @lapinkoira yes, I am using redis.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @lapinkoira Redis is v5.0.5

Comment: hmm, can you try with chord(short_tasks)(callback())

Comment: In the Task `task_group` you should use `add_together.s(args=(10, 1,))` then you should delay de chord

Comment: @Patricio Thanks. Your suggestion worked for me.

Comment: Can you give an example @Patricio

Comment: @Florian `chord_tasks = [task_a.s(args=..., kwargs=...), task_b.s(),...]` then you use that list in the chord `chord(chord_tasks, callback_task)` but basically your chord tasks should be [signatures](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=signature#celery.Signature) of your tasks, the callback should be a signature too